# InternetStackHelper class

Tags: ns-3

For the below code snippet

```
PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("5Mbps"));
pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

NetDeviceContainer devices;
devices = pointToPoint.Install (nodes);

InternetStackHelper stack;
stack.Install (nodes);

Ipv4AddressHelper address;
address.SetBase ("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");

Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces = address.Assign (devices);
```

What is the relevance of the code

```
InternetStackHelper stack;
stack.Install (nodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what's exactly not clear from [the documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_internet_stack_helper.html#details)?
It's a helper class which aggregates several objects, mainly for routing and tracing so e.g. when you have two nodes able to communicate over a NetDevice routing is done properly.